# EFI partitions after wiping out Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, efi

I've decided to wipe out dual booted-Ubuntu off my pc. However, i made a mistake of not dealing with the partitions before wiping Ubuntu off. Now, windows is not letting me extend my HDD with the space i had previously made by ubuntu(which is now unallocated). Partiton Manager pic:[Disk 0 is HDD which had Ubuntu while Disk 1 is SSD with windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Q2Q.png)

here's a link to the video of what exactly is happening in my computer:
https://youtu.be/bWNYwZ2ICpU

Comment: You have a very unusual layout. The EFI partition in the Disk 0 is what's preventing the expansion of the partition before it which is normal and expected. Now, first of all you need to find which drive is the first priority in the boot order at UEFI settings. If it's Disk 1 (120GB) then the EFI partition you need to keep is the one on that drive (260MB) and you can safely remove the EFI partition in Disk 0 (513MB) and then expand the partition. You just need to know what you're doing.

Comment: I had that in my mind, but windows is not letting me delete the EFI partition present in Disk 0(this is the one that's to be removed). It's a striped volume and when right clicked, there's no option other than 'help'.
P.S: Disk 1 is SSD with totally windows on it. I wouldn't want to touch it.

Comment: It makes sense the limited tools offered by Windows Disk Management errs on the side of caution. Third-party tools can do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the EFI partition on disk 0 and extend volume D:, you can use 3rd party partition software such as [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html) or [EaseUS 
Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/download/partition-manager.html) for Windows to do these operations.  They have more functionality than the built in Windows Disk Management console and they are free for personal (non-commercial) use.

Comment: Probably the EFI partition can be removed (read my comment above). **But if it can this answer is harmful**. EFI partitions - which are being used, of course - must be at the beginning of the drive.

Comment: The 513MB EFI partition on disk 0 is already the second partition in the [image uploaded by OP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Q2Q.png).  It could still be preserved if desired, while allowing the extension of volume D on disk 0.

Answer (score 0):

Booted into Ubuntu and used GParted, that solved everything. Thanks for the help anyway.